# When using "Replace": Excel VBA Automation Error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, vba

For a VBA code, I always have the same error when I want to replace a variable in the formula. Instead of using "Replace", what other ways can I replace the variable in the formula?

Thanks

```
wk.Worksheets("test").Rows(end_row & ":" & end_row).Select
Selection.Replace What:=xx1 & yy1, Replacement:=xx2 & yy2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
            , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: Hi, could you please create an minimal reproducible example? We would need CSV data from the sheet, and values for xx/yy--1/2.  In addition to what error you are receiving. Thank you!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What's that `, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2` all about? [Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace).